# Hibernate criterion.list() throws NullPointerException in mysterious circumstances

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, debugging

I have an array of strings like ["foo", "bar", "baz"]. I'm trying to find all records that contain either of these words, e.g by doing:

`SELECT * from city WHERE (name LIKE '%foo%' OR name LIKE '%bar%' OR name LIKE '%baz%')`.

Sometimes a state might also be present, in which as I'd need the query to be this:

`SELECT * from city WHERE (name LIKE '%foo%' OR name LIKE '%bar%' OR name LIKE '%baz%') AND stateId = 11`

I'm using Hibernate criteria for these searches, here is my method:

```
public static List<City> findByPartialName(State state, String... names)
{
    if (names.length <= 0)
        return null;

    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(City.class);
    boolean found = false;
    Criterion[] conditions = new Criterion[names.length];
    List<String> doneWords = new ArrayList<>( names.length );
    int i =0;
    for (String city : names)
    {
        city = city.trim();
        if (city.isEmpty() || city.length() < 3)
            continue;

        if ( doneWords.contains(city) )
            continue;

        found = true;
        conditions[i] = Restrictions.like("name", "%" + city + "%");
        doneWords.add(city);
        i++;
    }
    if (! found)
        return null;

    cr.add( Restrictions.or( conditions ) );

    if (state != null)
        cr.add( Restrictions.eq("state", state) );

    try
    {
        List<City> cities = cr.list();
        return cities;
    }
    catch (ObjectNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the very mysterious problem. As you can see, I'm using an `ArrayList` called `doneWords` to keep track of any words that have already been added. So if I pass in the array: `[Nashua, South, Nashua]`, then `Nashua` will only be added in an `OR` condition once, rather than duplicated.

If I pass in that exact array ( `[Nashua, South, Nashua]` ), then I get a null pointer exception on this line:

`List<City> cities = cr.list();`

However if I comment out this line:

`doneWords.add(city);`

then everything works fine (however `Nashua` is added twice in the query even though it only needs to be added once).

If I pass in an array which doesn't contain any duplicate words, e.g if I just pass in `[South, Nashua]`, then it also works even without commenting out the `doneWords.add(city)` line.

I'm very confused by this. What's going on here?

P.S I have `show_sql` option set to true, and I can see that no query is executed when the `NullPointerException` is thrown at `cr.list()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the array of Criterion, your array is sized to the number of names received even if it contains empty names, names smaller than 3 chars or duplicates. In those cases the array will contain less than names.length Criterion objects, the rest contains null references which causes your NPE. Instead of an array of Criterion you should use a List  and use toArray() to pass it to Restrictions.or().

Comment: i did not realize that the rest would be null.. thanks!